# How to find text in current file but match relative to cursor position [VS Code]?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a file opened in VS Code - 4000 lines long.
Folder is not loaded - just one file.

I am editing one method on line 3500.
If I press `Ctrl+F` and start typing it jumps to the first result in the whole file - line 500.

I want to find **all instances of search term bellow the current cursor position** (focused/selected line).
How to do it?

I used Notepad++ before and the case above works perfectly.

VS Code version: 1.19.1

Comment: You must be able to select the area of interest (all lines below the given one) and then search the for the term in the selected area only.

Comment: I could do that but that requires multiple keyboard shortcuts or multiple mouse click to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated VS Code to 1.19.2 and it works as expected (like in Notepad++).

`Ctrl+F` jumps to first result after current line (cursor position).

EDIT: 2022 update: version `1.66.2` does not jump at all - just marks results.